# CKEditor stripping out div class, despite it being specified in extraAllowedContent

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

CKEditor is stripping out div CLASS attributes when I switch to/from Source view.

This is the configuration:

```
$('.cke-editor-restrictive').ckeditor({
    extraAllowedContent: [
        "*[class,id]",
        "a[*]",
        "img[*]",
        "strong", "em", "small",
        "u", "s", "i", "b",
        "p", "blockquote[class,id]",
        "div[class,id,data-href]",
        "ul", "ol", "li",
        "br", "hr",
        "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6",
        "script[src,charset,async]",
        "iframe[*]", "embed[*]", "object[*]",
        "cite", "mark", "time",
        "dd", "dl", "dt",
        "table", "th", "tr", "td", "tbody", "thead", "tfoot"
    ].join("; ")
})
```

And the global CKEditor config:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
  config.extraPlugins = 'mediaembed,codemirror,autosave';
  config.codemirror = { ... };

  config.toolbar = [['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', "RemoveFormat"], ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Blockquote'], ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Image', 'MediaEmbed'], ['Find', 'Paste'], ['Source', 'Maximize']];

  config.bodyClass = 'ckeditor-body';
  config.contentsCss = "/assets/application.css";
  config.baseHref = "http://www.website.org/";
  config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;
};
```

What am I missing? I've been over [the documentation for Allowed Content Rules](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules) and it doesn't seem like I'm doing anything wrong. Even if I change the rule to `div[*]` it strips out the class.

Comment: Try in modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.config.js add this
config.allowedContent = true;

Comment: I don't want to disable the content filter.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Classes and styles are not handled together with other attributes. They have their own place in ACF rules. To enable all styles you would write:

```
'div{*}'
```

And to enable all classes:

```
'div(*)'
```

And to enable everything:

```
'div(*){*}[*]'
```

Comment: The documentation appears to have improved somewhat.  It's here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules

Answer (score 2):

when i write

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'div(class);ul(class)[id]';
```

`div` and the `ul` keep the specific `class`, but `id` always gets deleted.

is there any way to allow "id" ?

edit: got it!
to ALLOW ID ->

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'div(rslides_container);ul(rslides)[id]';
```

if you want ckeditor to **keep your ID do not change** [id] (do not use your ID! simple write [id] and ckeditor will not delete your id!

Comment: mkey.. 
Allowed Content Rule usually consists of four main parts:
elements, attributes, styles, classes